# Issue occured in generate pdf file using tc pdf

Tags: php

I will try to generate pdf file using tcpdf. but there are not generate proper out.
There are generate some binary code like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep8pU.png)

My Controller Code

```
$MYPDF_OBJ = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$MYPDF_OBJ->CoverPage($this->BasePath.'images/LeadImages/Arizona-Property-Investment-3-7087141.jpg');
$addCmdDetails = $MYPDF_OBJ->addCmdDetails();
$MYPDF_OBJ->MAP_OF_ALL_LISTINGS($POST['MAP_OF_ALL_LISTINGS']);
$comparable_array = array();
$comparable_array['comparable']['headers'] = array('Address','Beds','Baths','YrBlt','SqFt','Lot Size','Price','Sold Date');
foreach($array as $MyArray){
    $comparable_array['comparable']['data'] = $MyArray;
    $MYPDF_OBJ->compatableProperties($comparable_array);
}

$MYPDF_OBJ->propertyDetails($getData);
//$MYPDF_OBJ->Output($this->BasePath.'\images\pdf\file.pdf', 'F');
$MYPDF_OBJ->Output('yourfilename.pdf', 'D');
//echo $pdf->Output(); exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean? PDF files are binary data. that looks like the binary data of a PDF file to me, but interpreted as text. the `content-type` http header tells your browser what the output is, and how to interpret it. i bet your server told the browser `Content-Type: text/html`, and then just outputted the binary data of a PDF file. so the browser, being told that it was html, tried to render it as such, and because the PDF format and the HTML format are completely incompatible, you got that garbage rendering. to tell the browser `this is a PDF file, treat it as such`, send the HTTP header `Content-Type: application/pdf`

to set a header in PHP, use the header() function, eg

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
```

Comment: +1 - this is the best answer for this, as the OP is also seeing the binary, he must be using a text editor to view it, I suggest opening with Chrome / Adobe PDF Viewer

Comment: I will add header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); but still issue occured.

I will add like that.

header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
   //$MYPDF_OBJ->Output('yourfilename.pdf', 'D');
   echo $MYPDF_OBJ->Output(); exit;

Comment: @AkashShah show me a screenshot of the rendering with the proper content-type header, also do a curl request with the `-I` parameter to the same pdf url, and screenshot curl's output too.

Comment: There are no curl request.

See my content header code like this.

header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
   $MYPDF_OBJ = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

echo $MYPDF_OBJ->Output(); exit;

Comment: @AkashShah i know there is no curl request, but make one. download & install curl ( https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin ) , open your terminal and run `curl -I http://127.0.0.1/path/to/PDFscript.php` , what output do you get?